# If Ida Been Here, Ida Been There

Tags: sentence-meaning, ellipsis, contractions

I am curious to know what this sentence mean. One thing I may get right, I think, Ida is short for "I'd have".

> If Ida Been Here, Ida Been There

Album by Craobh Rua, native of Belfast, or so I think.

Note: I did not listen to, but I am curious about the title.

Comment: Apparently so: **I'da** [wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/I'da) *Contraction of I would have.* You can also have *he'da*, etc. But since *Ida* is usually written *I'da*, something else could be going on, since *Ida* is (also) a name. And if you're not going to listen to it, neither am I. :)

Comment: In other words, *Ida* is probably just a writing/spelling of *I'da* without using the apostrophe.

Comment: I wonder what good can possibly come of listening when the sentence is a title of the album; unless it is in a song. Well, on second thought, maybe I could get the meaning if listened. It'd be something figurative, but more to the point, I learned that it is not an idiomatic phrase or a cultural reference. Thanks @AlanCarmack

Answer (score 1):

Your title

> If Ida Been Here, Ida Been There

could have two meanings

> 1) If I *would have* been here, I *would have* been there

Ida is also a female name, so

> 2) If Ida *(would had)* been here, then Ida *(would have)* been there

However, the band you are referring to is from Belfast, so the first interpretation is probably correct.  It is along the same contractions as "gonna" and "woulda".

Comment: +1 As such, it's a possible shortened or respelling of *I'd of* (= *I would of* = *I would have*), which of course is formally incorrect, but written as dialog sometimes. Interesting the *-f* sound gets totally elided in *I'da*.